# 00900. 00000 - "invalid SQL statement" for EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

Tags: oracle11g

I am trying to use Dynamic query in my code below but getting error (00900. 00000 -  "invalid SQL statement"). Kindly suggest where i am mistaking in the code.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE CreateInsertTmpTable
AS
crttmp VARCHAR2(200);
intrtmp VARCHAR2(200);
printTableValues VARCHAR2(1000);

BEGIN
  crttmp := 'CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE my_temp_table ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS AS SELECT * FROM VWBLKDATA WHERE 1=0';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE crttmp;
  intrtmp := 'INSERT INTO my_temp_table SELECT * FROM VWBLKDATA';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE intrtmp;
  printTableValues := ' for data in(SELECT * from my_temp_table)
                        loop
                             dbms_output.put_line(data.ID); 
                        end loop';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE printTableValues;
  COMMIT;
END CreateInsertTmpTable;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're overdoing the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE; you can run INSERT statements and PL/SQL without them like:

```
begin 
for i in 1..10 loop
   insert into test (some_column) values (to_char(i));
end loop;
end;
```

But anyways, it looks like you're last EXECUTE IMMEDIATE is trying to execute a partial PL/SQL anonymous block; it's missing a "begin" and "end;"

I would suggest just executing the for loop like so:

```
for data in (SELECT * from my_temp_table) 
loop
      dbms_output.put_line(data.ID); 
end loop;
```

or else you'll need to add a begin/end around it in the text (and the "end loop" needs a trailing ";"):

```
printTableValues := 'begin 
                        for data in (SELECT * from my_temp_table)
                        loop
                             dbms_output.put_line(data.ID); 
                        end loop;
                     end;';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @patrick marchand for your suggestions. I tried my code with begin and end..it worked but desired o/p is not generated(ie i want to print the global temp data). Actually my task is to create GTT on fly inside SP and hence took help of Dynamic SQL. I just want to do a test to print all table data using the above FOR loop but data is not displayed in op however the script run successfully. I request you to please suggest how to print the table data using Execute Immediate.

Comment: Actually for learning purpose i am doing this test wherein i am trying to achieve following thing from an SP 
1) Create GTT 
2) Insert data into GTT from an existing View
3) Print all the GTT data.
4) DROP GTT

Since my SP is going to execute an DLL hence everything is going to be Dynamic....please suggest id can still run DLL inside SP in better way. Thanks

Comment: And even when i am adding some clause in my dynamic string like below, i am getting error(PLS-00103), Please suggest what is going wrong in the code.

printTableValues := 'BEGIN 
                       for data in(SELECT * from my_temp_table WHERE LOC = 'I')
                        loop
                             dbms_output.put_line(data.ID); 
                        end loop;
                        END;';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE printTableValues;

Comment: Hi @patrickmarchand , code is now working as expected. It was my mistake in logic. Thanks
I request if you could please help me understand why i am getting error when using clause (WHERE LOC = 'I') as below

printTableValues := 'BEGIN for data in(SELECT * from my_temp_table WHERE LOC = 'I') 

loop 

dbms_output.put_line(data.ID); 

end loop; 

END;'; 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE printTableValues;

Comment: @PS078 If you want to have something like "WHERE LOC = 'I'" embedded in a text string, you need to double-up the single quotes around the "I". So, instead of 'BEGIN....WHERE LOC = 'I' ... END;' you need to have it as 'BEGIN....WHERE LOC = ''I'' ... END;' (there are two consecutive single quotes before and after the constant.)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Patrick Marchand , shall implement my code as suggested by you.